# Simple mod_rewrite is not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do a simple mod_rewrite. Below are the contents of my localhost/wordpress/.htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
  RewriteEngine on  
  RewriteRule /([0-9]+) /?page_id=$1
</IfModule>
```

I've checked that mod_rewrite module is present (using phpinfo()) and it appears to be. Actually it wasn't before, I enabled it using `sudo a2enmod rewrite`.

For this test, I want to rewrite:

localhost/wordpress/13 -> localhost/wordpress/?page_id=13

Actually, in the end I just want to do:

localhost/wordpress/photos -> localhost/wordpress/?page_id=13

.. can't get either to work. Am I writing the rule wrong? Or should I check somewhere in Apache, perhaps something I've not setup right? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to include *wordpress* folder in rule's path.

You can do it this way

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^photos$ /wordpress/index.php?page_id=13 [L]
```

Or this way (both are equivalent)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteRule ^photos$ index.php?page_id=13 [L]
```

Comment: Don't forget to give a feedback. Did this work for you ? Or do you still have some problem about it ?